# Why isn't there a vertical asymptote at $x = -1$ for $f(x) = \frac{(x^3-1)(\ln(x+2))}{2x^3+3x^2-2x-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why isn't there a vertical asymptote at $x = -1$ for $f(x) = \frac{(x^3-1)(\ln(x+2))}{2x^3+3x^2-2x-3}$

I understand that there is a removable discontinuity at x = 1 since $x^3 - 1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$ but I don't know how x = -1 is not a vertical asymptote.

Comment: as $x$ approaches $-1, \ln(x+2)$ approaches $0,$ creating an indeterminate form and another discontinuity, but not necessarily an asymptote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

The denominator is
$$(2x+3)(x-1)(x+1) $$

and we use

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac {\ln (x+2)}{x+1}=$$

$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac {\ln (X+1)}{X}=1$$

we find that
$$\lim_{x\to-1}f (x)=\frac {-2}{-2}=1$$

Thus, there is No vertical asymptote at $x=-1$ since the limit is finite.